# escape % Wildcard in prepared statement

Tags: mysql, go

The following code returns an error:

```
stmt, err := DBCon.Prepare("SELECT * FROM item WHERE market_hash_name LIKE '%?%' ")
handle_error(err)
res, err := stmt.Query(market_hash_name)
```

the error:
`2022/07/09 19:57:56 http: panic serving <ip> sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1`

this statement works:

`stmt, err := DBCon.Prepare("SELECT * FROM item WHERE market_hash_name LIKE ? ")`

How can I escape the `%`sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I escape the %sign?

The problem is not the percent sign, the problem is that `?` is inside a [string literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html), which makes it a literal question mark and not a parameter placeholder. And because the statement does not recognize the literal question mark as a parameter placeholder it expects NO arguments, which is why the error says: `expected 0 arguments`.

---

To add `%` to the argument you have at least two options:

1. Add the percent signs to the Go argument `market_hash_name`, e.g.

```golang
stmt.Query("%"+market_hash_name+"%")
```

2. Concatenate the percent signs to the `?` in the SQL string with

```sql
CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
```